# Populating select tag from selected items in php

Tags: php, html, forms, select

i am totally new on PHP and I have an issue, i hope i can explain my problem exactly.

I have two HTML5 forms where one of the form is being populated by php for loop and inside the same form there is there is a submit button code as follows:

```
<form class="" name="upgradeChosen" role="form" method="post" action='index.php?action=upgradeChosen'>
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <select name="upgradeSelected" id="ID_UPGRADE_SELECTED">
            <?
            foreach ($arrayUpgrade as $value) {
                $pro = $value->getnewProduct();
                echo '<option value="'.$value->getId().'">'.$pro->getName()." "."===>". $pro->getPrice(Currency::getCurrentCurrency()).'</option>';
            }
            ?>   
        </select>
    </div>
    <button style="margin-top: 40px" id="ID_CREATE_ESTIMATE" type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><i class="icon-rocket"></i>Create estimate</button>
</form>
```

Inside the another PHP file there is a function which is called function upgradeChosen and it parses the selected data from select tag. at the second form i would like to generate a list and populate the selected items from first listbox or select tag. Is this possible ?

Here is my second form code as follows:

```
<form class ="" name ="upgradeEstimate" role="form" method="post" action='index.php?action=Frontend_upgradeEstimate'>
</form>
```

and the function which is called upgradeChosen code as follows:

```
public function upgradeChosen (){

        $idUpgradeLine = $this->getRequestAttribute("upgradeSelected");

        $upgrade = new UpgradeRates($idUpgradeLine);

        $product = $upgrade->getNewProduct();
 }
```

please help me to achieve this if there is a way of doing it only with php i will be happy i do not want to use Jquery, JavaScript or AJAX at first stage if there is a way how to do it with php only.

Comment: Since you are using php, and post method, once you submit the form, the value from select tag would be available to use using $_POST['selectedtagname'] in your second page.

Comment: yes it is available but how i am going to populate the second listbox i want to create a listbox actually with a selected value from first list thanks

Comment: Please elaborate your question. I didn't get. From which page to which page you want your data to flow as select dropdown.

Comment: <?php $selected = $_POST['tagname'];  if($selected == "fruits") { echo "<select><option>apple</option><option>mango</option><option>banana</option></select>";} ?>

Comment: At the first form i have a dropdown list and list of items where it is populated with a for loop and from that menu i would like to choose an item and add it to second form or if it is possible a list box inside the first form does not really matter which way... the important thing to find the solution really

Comment: You can also go for session array, if you wanna store multiple values between page calls. Or local storage or session storage, if you wanna use Javascript.

Comment: Every time user choses an item i am submitting the page that is the case is there way to when i submit fill an array and afterwards with a session array i can parse it and create the list is that what you mean? Because in objective-c you can fill the arrays with objects one by one basically i am a mobile app developer :) php is bit complicated for me

Answer (score -1):

For this you must use javascript.
You can use onchange event of your select for call a javascript function and reload your page with a post param. Then write your second select in php.

I think there aren't any other method.

Fabio Del Rosso.